# SQL DB Diagram Extract

Tags: sql-server, entity-relationship

I am using SQL Server 2011 and need to create a visual representation (diagram). The current structure has no relationships (Foreign Keys) between tables and there are tables without any Primary Keys.

I have tried using SQL Database Diagrams but can't add any relationship between tables without the change happening on the DB itself.

I want to draw relationships without it making any changes.

Are there any free DB Diagram software that I can use in order to achieve this? I have tried DbVisualizer but getting same issues as with the diagram within SQL.

Comment: You could download it as an image and use any image editor to "draw" the relationship lines between tables. Just out of curiosity, is there any reason why you would have a database with no foreign keys defined?

Comment: If I can find software that can automatically draw the relationships based on column name, that would help a lot as I have over 500 tables currently in the DB. No idea why this DB has been created the way it has (without FKs). The current DBA has been struggling with rubbish data for quite some time.

Comment: If you have no foreign keys defined how do you expect the software to identify the relationships? By guessing? By rolling a dice? This is a good example on why foreign constraints are needed: not only to preserve the integrity of your data, but also to *document* your model

Comment: haha thanks @a_horse_with_no_name , yeah I understand what you are saying. Hopefully there is software that can draw the relationship based on column name alone. I have been tasked to clean the DB and get it in a stable state. First step for me would be to see a visual representation of the DB structure.

Comment: You can try to create a script which generates ALTER TABLE ... based on column name and then create and empty DB with modifyied schema and use any diagrammer available to modify FKs

Comment: You should probably attack this both ways. A diagram is helpful for understanding how the relationships _should_ be (even if it isn't reflected in the data). But you also need to clean up the data and apply FK's. If you have 500 tables then this is a huge job and you need to prioritise it somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I would do the following:

1. Generate scripts for your database (schema only) (as @Serg suggested already)

   You can do this using `SSMS`: Right click your database - `Tasks - Generate Scripts`. Select all tables and then under `Advanced`, select `Schema only` at the `Types  of data to script`. Save script and run it in some test environment to  generate a `schema only` copy of your database. (If doing this on the same  server, you might need to change the script a little, to give the new database another name)
2. Dynamically try to "guess" the foreign key relationships

   Since you have 500+ tables, you could try to make [this script](https://sqlsunday.com/2017/04/10/guessing-fk-constraints/) work for
   you (of course it would need some testing and tuning to adapt it for your
   case) but I used it in the following scenario and it worked.

Hopefully you do have a naming convention. In this script it is assumed that the referenced keys are named the same, but this can be configured.

So, I created the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE test (testid int identity(1,1) UNIQUE, description varchar(10))
CREATE TABLE test_item (id int identity(1,1) UNIQUE, testid int)
```

And the following indexes on their primary keys (normally, you should have them too)

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ix_testid] ON [dbo].[test]([testid] ASC) 
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ix_testitemid] ON [dbo].[test_item]([id] ASC)
```

I did not create a foreign key relationship.

Next I ran the script from the [Automatically guessing foreign key constraints](https://sqlsunday.com/2017/04/10/guessing-fk-constraints/) article and I managed to get the following result:

[image]

Executing all the `ALTER` statements generated from this script you could get your relationships created in your new database - generate the diagram from this database and you are done! :)

ps. I would suggest you test it out step by step, for example with one table first and then adding others and checking the results.
You can try a working demo of my little test [here](http://rextester.com/CUS71560).

Good luck!

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! I will definitely follow these steps!